# MySQL Server terminated and hibernate database connection not closing

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, database-connection

I have used the following code to create database connection using Hibernate configuration file.

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.username">xxx</property>
<property name="connection.password">xxx</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>


<!-- C3PO Connection pool setting -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">900</property> -->
<!-- Connection pool setting -->
```

It seems connections are opening and closing successfully. If 10 users accessing the website at same time my website login page spinning long time after 5 or 10 minutes the server getting down. Also the I could not restart the mysql server it says process Unexpectedly terminated. Then I have to install mysql server again. This is happening in my production server. I lost so many real data for this problem.

Please can anyone suggest me to use database connection effectively while accessing 10000 users at a time. What is the best approach to handling this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. Build a test server, run a load tester (JMeter is OK) and replicate the problem -- so you can see what's happening, without real data at risk.

You don't have enough information at the moment, to be able to identify the problem.

Once you can replicate the problem, try changing JDBC driver & database versions, and related components. But make sure your changes are going to fix the problem, by re-creating it first.

The other thing this could be symptomatic of, is **hard disk drive starting to fail**.  If not only your data got damaged, but you had to reinstall the software as well.. Not common, but beware.

---

And why did restarting/ or (if necessary) reinstalling MySQL, not have your data retained in the database files?

Comment: Yes, I have writtent small piece of code to check whether connection closing or not. In my debug mode connection closing successfully. I dont know why connections are increasing in production mysql server. If it reaches around 150 the server getting down. I am new to the mysql. Actually I lost my real data then I re installed again. How do I get real data without uninstalling mysql server?.

Comment: Try using JMeter to reproduce the problem. Without being able to reproduce it, you can't know any change you make is actually gonna fix it. You'll just be waiting for the next outage/ loss-of-data event, and potentially suffer several of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate configuration looks correct, I think it is the database that is the cause of these problems here.

Regardless of the problems it is experiencing it should not terminate, therefore it looks as an operating system issue such as:

- MySQL runs out of memory
- MySQL is consuming too much CPU power and is killed by the kernel
- there is no disk space available on the partition where MySQL runs

Comment: Thanks Adam! As per your instruction I have verified the following things in my server. Mysql server installed in C Drive having 5 GB disk space. While many users accessing the server connections are increasing gradually. If its reaches above 160 or 180 connection application starting spinning. If its going 5 minutes the system getting or restarted.

Comment: What is the memory usage once there are more than 160 or 180 connections? Does your machine has a lot of the virtual memory available? If you running on Linux [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) might be helpful.

Comment: My system configuration is Windows 2008 R2, C - Drive memory space 30 GB, Free space 5 GB(Installed mysql in C Drive), RAM 2 GB. Do you think is this enough configuration?

Comment: 2GB for MySQL and an Java application (Application server? Web container?) to service more than 100 up to 1000 simultaneous users? Up to 1000 Java threads, 1000 database connections? I think it is way too low, but as this is not based on any tests, like it should be, it is only my guess. I think we are getting away from the original question, which in my opinion has been answered already.